# Add textual property to nodes in igraph with R

Tags: r, properties, label, vertex, igraph

I have some issue while adding properties of nodes in igraph working with R. I made a text list named journal.txt and I want to give the nodes of my graph a property. With other textual or numeric lists, I had absolutely no issues, but with this one I have.

with this I read the txt file, read just the first column, although there is just one, read as character, although i tried also without and it doesn't work

```
journalList = read.csv("c:/temp/biblioCoupling/journals.txt", header=FALSE)
journalLR = (journalList[1:303,1]) 
journalLR = as.character(journalLR) 
V(g)$journalName = journalLR
```

then when I save the file,

```
write.graph(gr,"filename.gml",format=c("gml"), creator="Claudio Biscaro")
```

I see all other properties I added to nodes, but not this one!!!

could it be because some entry in journalLR is more than 15 character long?
I have absolutely no idea why I can't do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not reproducible, it is impossible to tell for sure, but I guess that `V(g)$journalName` is a complex attribute, i.e. it is not a vector of values, but a list of values.

To check, you can do `str(g)` and then look at the code letter after the `journalName` attribute. If it is `x`, then it is complex, if it is `c`, then it is character.

If this is the problem and you don't really need a list, then the workaround is to do

```
g <- remove.vertex.attribute(g, "journalName")
V(g)$journalName <- journalName
```

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding one at a time. That was weird. after a long time trying!

```
for (i in 1:length(journalLR))
{
  V(g)[i]$journalName = journalLR[i]
}
```

probably it is not a formally good solution, but it works!